# How to do schema validation to get missing references with SaxonJS

Tags: node.js, saxon-js

If I have a simple xsd file and a simple xml file, can SaxonJS show which elements and which attributes in the xml are not defined in the xsd?

I have been looking around for examples but haven't been able to find anything so far.

**Update**

I'll also accept an answer with js code (node) that uses saxon-js to traverse trough a xml resource and checks elements and attributes (doesn't have to check attribute values) in a xsd resource.

In a somewhat efficient way.

Comment: (Schema based) validation is not a feature of Saxon-JS, as far as I am aware. Schema based validation is something that Saxon EE for Java, .NET or C/C++ provides, but not Saxon-JS.

Comment: Can you show a small but representative schema and instance sample? "Simple xsd file" is easy to say but in my opinion most schemas are not "simple", the power and flexibility of nesting and combining the various options of types, particles make it hard to come up with something easy and simple in XSLT. I think Saxonica has an in-house schema validator implemented in XSLT but I have no idea whether they would want to commercialize it and whether Saxon-JS can handle it. It might make sense to contact them directly at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon-js if nobody shows up here.

Comment: Also, "which elements and which attributes in the xml are not defined" is vague, it might be easy to use a key into the schema to find any `foo` element declaration for a `foo` in the instance sample but that doesn't really tell whether that particular declaration is in the right place for the instance element to be valid.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Are you saying that saxon-js does not load an xsd resource as an xsd? But just as xml? I assumed once an xsd is loaded you can look up elements in some sort of tree structure

Comment: I am not sure where you expect or see XSD processing in an XPath 3.1 and XSLT 3.0 implementation like Saxon-JS, unless it supported schema-aware XSLT and XPath, which Saxon-JS doesn't, as far as I know. So parsing/processing XSD as any XML document with XSLT/XPath seems possible, but certainly not as a comprehensive tool to replace a schema validator or a schema object model.

Answer (score 0):

To simply check the existence of an `xs:element` element in the schema a key would suffice, the same for `xs:attribute`. But all that relies on simple `xs:element name="foo"` and `xs:attribute name="att1"` declarations being used and in no way checks the nesting or structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="element-by-name" match="xs:element" use="QName(/*/@targetNamespace, @name)"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="attribute-by-name" match="xs:attribute" use="QName(/*/@targetNamespace, @name)"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(key('element-by-name', node-name(), $schema-doc))]">
    <element-not-declared>
      <name>{node-name()}</name>
      <path>{path()}</path>
    </element-not-declared>
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*[not(key('attribute-by-name', node-name(), $schema-doc))]">
    <attribute-not-declared>
      <name>{node-name()}</name>
      <path>{path()}</path>
    </attribute-not-declared>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:comment xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} {system-property('Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}platform')}</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:param name="schema-doc">
    <xs:schema>
      <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="items">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
  </xsl:param>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <items count="1">
    <item>
      <foo>foo 1</foo>
      <bar>bar 1</bar>
    </item>
  </items>
</root>
```

when run with Saxon-JS 2.3 in the browser gives

```xml
    <attribute-not-declared>
       <name>count</name>
       <path>/Q{}root[1]/Q{}items[1]/@count</path>
    </attribute-not-declared>
    <element-not-declared>
       <name>bar</name>
       <path>/Q{}root[1]/Q{}items[1]/Q{}item[1]/Q{}bar[1]</path>
    </element-not-declared>
    <!--Run with Saxon-JS 2.3 Browser-->
```

but I have tested that it works with "Saxon-JS 2.3 Node.js" as well.

So this finds some elements or attributes for which no matching declaration is found, based on the keys used into the schema. It is just meant as a superficial approach, not even taking the complications of namespaces and elementForm or attributeForm and namespaces into account.

To run XSLT 3 code with SaxonJS, you can either run the XSLT using `SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate` calling the XPath 3.1 `transform` function, as shown below, or you can first use the `xslt3` command line tool to export the XSLT to SEF/JSON which can then be run using `SaxonJS.transform`.

```
const SaxonJS = require("saxon-js");

const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <items count="1">
    <item>
      <foo>foo 1</foo>
      <bar>bar 1</bar>
    </item>
  </items>
</root>`;

const xsd = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="element-by-name" match="xs:element" use="QName(/*/@targetNamespace, @name)"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="attribute-by-name" match="xs:attribute" use="QName(/*/@targetNamespace, @name)"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(key('element-by-name', node-name(), $schema-doc))]">
    <element-not-declared>
      <name>{node-name()}</name>
      <path>{path()}</path>
    </element-not-declared>
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*[not(key('attribute-by-name', node-name(), $schema-doc))]">
    <attribute-not-declared>
      <name>{node-name()}</name>
      <path>{path()}</path>
    </attribute-not-declared>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:comment xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} {system-property('Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}platform')}</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:param name="schema-doc">
    <xs:schema>
      <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="items">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
  </xsl:param>

</xsl:stylesheet>`;


const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`
  transform(
    map {
      'source-node' : parse-xml($xml),
      'stylesheet-text' : $xsd,
      'delivery-format' : 'serialized'
      }
  )?output`,
  [],
  {
    params : { xml : xml, xsd : xsd }
  }
);

console.log(result);
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attribute-not-declared>
   <name>count</name>
   <path>/Q{}root[1]/Q{}items[1]/@count</path>
</attribute-not-declared>
<element-not-declared>
   <name>bar</name>
   <path>/Q{}root[1]/Q{}items[1]/Q{}item[1]/Q{}bar[1]</path>
</element-not-declared>
<!--Run with Saxon-JS 2.3 Node.js-->
```

Comment: To be honest: I as looking for "js code (node)"

Comment: I haven't thanked you yet for your (extensive) answer. Thank you! It's very helpful.  Unfortunately when I saw you added the js code, I couldn't award the bounty anymore.